# How can I remove <div ="mceTemp"> using built in wordpress filters

Tags: tinymce

I'm getting image fields wrapped in  tags and would like to remove the surrounding divs, but only if they are of class "mceTemp". Anyone know of an efficient way to do this?

Also, should those Divs even be there?

Comment: So I wrote a recursive function which sort of works:

Comment: function recursive_replace($string) {
    preg_match('/<div class\=[\"]mceTemp[\"]\>(.*?)<\/div>/si',$string,$matches);

    if($matches) {

 $string = preg_replace('/<div class\=[\"]mceTemp[\"]\>(.*?)<\/div>/si','$1',$string);

 recursive_replace($string);
    } else {

 return $string;
    }
}

Comment: feel free to improve on it!

Comment: Normally you should not run over those as tinymce removes them on it's own.

Comment: I'm wondering if the plugin custom field templates is the culprit. Someone installed this and made a mess of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with hakre - something funky is going on elsewhere, those shouldnt be appearing.

As a sidenote, you could use the jQuery unwrap() function to remove those divs.

```
jQuery('div.mceTemp img').unwrap();
```

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: cool. That is good to know ;-)